# Cloud function uses GeoPoint class from different node module

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am running a firebase cloud function and firebase firestore.
When trying to store a GeoPoint instance into firestore the following error is logged on firebase:

```
Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Detected an object of type "GeoPoint" that doesn't match the expected instance. Please ensure that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package.
at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isDocument] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)
at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:286:14)
at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:420:8)
at exports.initializeActivityStructure.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/user_code/lib/index.js:86:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24
```

The error indicates that the GeoPoint class I am using is not the correct one. The function runs fine when running it locally using `firebase functions:shell`.

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@google-cloud/firestore": "0.14.1",
  "firebase-admin": "5.12.1",
  "firebase-functions": "1.0.4",
  ... 
}
```

I tried different versions here and settled on the exact ones that work when executing the code offline.

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as spacetime from 'spacetime';
import { DocumentSnapshot, GeoPoint } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
admin.initializeApp();

...

export const newDocument = functions.firestore.document('/someCollection/{documentKey}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return snapshot.ref.set({
        gps: new GeoPoint(10.0, 10.0),
       ...
    });
}
```

I would really appreciate any input on this, as it's clear that it's some sort of dependency problem, but the exact same versions work when testing offline.

Comment: try using `firebase.firestore.GeoPoint` instead of just `GeoPoint`

Comment: Using `admin.firestore.GeoPoint` (from firebase-admin) works.
Still wondering if this is the intended use or a bug, as it seems a little weird not to use the classes from packages that they where originally declared in.

Comment: Correction to the above: Using `admin.firestore.GeoPoint` works for saving the GeoPoint, but after that ANY operation (like change listeners) on that document throw an exception `Error: Argument "latitude" is not a valid number.
    at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isNumber] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)`.
Only removing the property from the document (manually) and re-adding a new GeoPoint in the web interface fixes this.

Comment: I'm also facing Error: Argument "latitude" is not a valid number error when trying to retrieve from firestore. Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use `gps: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.0, 10.0)`

Comment: Any reason why?